# Read a smartcard in a webapplication

Tags: java

How can i read a smartcard from a webapplication?

I know that this is not direct possible because there is the browser sandbox which has no access to hardware on the client side.
The only thing i have found so far were browser plugins, which were based on NPAPI. Unfortunatelythis is NPAPI
no longer supported by new browser versions. So this is not a solution.

How can i access a smartcard but otherwise. Is there a open source or commercial solution?
A solution working with windows os should be sufficient.

The smartcard reader is accessible via PC/SC.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have implemented a smartcard reader using a USB device and a java proxy to a windows .DLL driver. Are you intereste to know more? I can get more information when I'm home tonight. The hard part is the .java -> .dll part, since the libraries are native and quite low level.

Comment: Java WebStart (JNLP)

Comment: Thank you. At the moment i am hoping that there is more convenient way....;-) But from curiosity out: How do you install/update your solution on the client side, manually? And how can you access your proxy from javascript?

Comment: @JoopEggen: I know JNLP and JWS. But what is your solution behind this?

Comment: Just that a browser-restricted client-server solution will not do. In contrast WebStart app runs on the client, but has a server distribution. About smartcard programming I did not want to say anything, sorry.

Comment: Apologies i didn't read the *web* application part. I think you need a standalone app, if not that the web server itself can be couple to a card reader (e.g. running on a laptop).

Comment: @JoopEggen: OK. But i have unfortunately an existing browser-webapplication. And in this application i need smarcard access.....

Comment: You'll find it difficult to get outside the sandbox. Can you make a REST call to another web server, and doing the smart card access from there?

Comment: @vikingsteve: Yes this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Due to sandbox limitations, it's unlikely you can do this in the web app.

Please consider this approach:

Set yourself up a Jersey server with a rest endpoint like `/api/card/{cardnumber}` and do the java -> .dll bridge on the server side to talk to the card reader device.

If you are lucky there may already exist a java library to talk to the smart card reader (download the jar and use it).

Call that rest endpoint with an http GET operation from your web app.